# Can a community user create a new case from the record list quick actions on the Napili template

Tags: case, community, action, new

I would like to enable community users to create cases against my custom Unit object am I able to add the action on the record list?

In the winter16 release notes it says "Related record lists: Users can now access row-level actions (edit, delete, and so on) from related record lists." This leads me to believe I can add more action than currently available.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_networks_templates_more_record_actions_napili.htm

[image: Record list]